# Hackerrank challenge timout

Tags: c, algorithm, timeout

hey i am just trying to solve a challenge on hackerrank but in some test cases the code timeouts and i don't know why. [This is the challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation).

And here is my code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){
    int n, k, q; 
    scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&k,&q);
    int qs[q];
    int a[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < q; i++){
        scanf("%d",&qs[i]);
    }

    int lastNbr = a[n-1];
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
        lastNbr = a[n-1];
        for(int j = n - 1; j > -1; j--){
            a[j] = (j-1 >= 0) ? a[j-1] : lastNbr;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < q; i++){
        printf("%d\n", a[qs[i]]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, as you wrote: **you** are trying to solve it. Wouldn't be fair if **we** did ... - Do you have a **specific** question?

Comment: The secret is you don't need to rotate the array; the `%` operator is your friend.

Comment: @Olaf i mean when i submit the code the most test cases  are working but some timeout. It would be great if you would give me a hint in which part of my code the timeout occurs. :)

Comment: The code execution was not completed in the required time, and doing that is *part of the challenge*. If it is timing out even on the test cases, you need a serious rethink of the algorithm.

Comment: If you can't solve, that's why the editorial is there for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, lets start with analysing your algorithm's time complexity:

You have the 2 nested for loops which always go for `n * k` operations, as you rotate your array `k` times and you need `n` operations to make the rotation.

This goes as `O(n * k)`, so it's about `10^10` operations on the worst case input, which is quite too much for this task.

Please read [this](http://discrete.gr/complexity/) article first about how to calculate an algorithm's complexity, as it provides very useful information and it's explained with practical examples.

Now, you have to rethink your algorithm and get a better time complexity. I won't spoil the solution to you, but I can give you a hint: Think that you don't really need to rotate your array `k` times by `1` unit, you can instead do it only once by `k` units.

Hope this helps, good luck in solving the challenge! :)

Comment: Note that part of the challenge is for the OP to complete execution in the required time - if s/he cannot then s/he has failed.  If we answer for him/her, what have they learned (besides asking for help is easier than learning yourself)

Comment: I didn't spoil the solution, I only gave a hint and an article about studying time complexities. Maybe s/he doesn't have all these knowledge yet and doesn't know where to start studying for. Also, if you can't figure out a problem's solution , you ask for a hint, you don't just spend more time on it. Personally I believe that thinking too long at a problem, even though you figure it out after 1-2 weeks, it's pretty much lost time.

Comment: @VladTarniceru thank you very much for your help. And yes i am pretty new in this algorithm topic so i don't really have much knowledge in this area also i just started to learn c.

Comment: @VladTarniceru I have spent 1-2 weeks on some of the difficult challenge problems. Some I solved, some I did not. In the process I acquired in-depth knowledge of the topic. This comes under the heading "recreation", so I consider  none of it *wasted* time: like the fisherman who lost a catch, it was all about the pleasure of "being there", and the hope of making that catch.

Comment: @WeatherVane the longest I spend on a problem was 2 months. Yes, I agree, it is definitely fun to think for a longer period at a problem but sometimes you have to know when to say "Stop, I'll ask for a hint". Most people don't actually have 2 weeks to spend on a single problem because the whole process would be too slow. I had all the time in the world when I was 13 and started studying algorithms, but right now, if I can't figure out the solution of a problem in 3 hours at most I take a look on the solution. It's just that I don't have that much time as I did and I want to cover most topics.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your code it is o (n*k) solution. You can solve it in o (n) time. And input size is 10 pow 5 that's why you are getting time out error. % will help you out here.